# Calculate average of numbers in Gallery in a Powerapp

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am currently making a powerapp where students should be able to enter their grades. I'm currently working on the function to display the average and run into the problem that I can't use a Set() in a ForAll(). I have all the grades for the average in a gallery.

The code I have so far, but which does not work is

```
Set(sum, 0);
Set(weight, 0);

ForAll(
    GradeGallery.AllItems,
    sum = sum  + ThisRecord.Note * ThisRecord.Gewichtung;
    weight = weight + ThisRecord.Gewichtung;
);

Set(average, sum / weight)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Apps's language (Power Fx) is its core a declarative (functional) language, not an imperative one: while there are some ways to do imperative calculations, you'll get the best of the platform if you avoid them. In this case, you can use the following expression to calculate the average for the gallery's items:

```
Sum(GradeGallery.AllItems, ThisRecord.Note * ThisRecord.Gewichtung) /
    Sum(GradeGallery.AllItems, ThisRecord.Gewichtung)
```

Notice that this may result in a division by zero if there are no items in the gallery, so you can use something like the expression below to avoid that:

```
With(
    { all: GradeGallery.AllItems },
    If(
        CountRows(all) = 0,
        0,
        Sum(all, Note * Gewichtung) / Sum(all, Gewichtung)))
```